# How do I get the windows product key from cmd/powershell

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe

I need to get the product key of my PC using cmd or powershell. How do I get that?

OS Info: Windows 10 64-bit Pro

Comment: It is unnecessary to know your Windows 10 product key.  What problem are you trying to solve by knowing your product key for Windows 10?  One does not simply get the product key with PowerShell, it is more involved, but [ShowKeyPlus](https://github.com/Superfly-Inc/ShowKeyPlus/releases/tag/ShowkeyPlus) will show your product key

Comment: Saw this on a another thread awhile ago, works for what i need, but i cant test on Windows 10 non OEM `WinRM` needs to be enabled

https://www.warrenheld.com/retrieve-windows-product-keys-network/

Comment: I have found a way to get that! (@SQLTemp WinRm is enabled on my computer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like using using batch or powershell is very tough here. I have found a code in VBScript from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30255656/vbscript-to-return-windows-product-key

> ```
> const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
>
> strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion"
> strValueName = "DigitalProductId"
> strComputer = "."
> dim iValues()
>
> Set oReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _ 
>   strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
> oReg.GetBinaryValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,strValueName,iValues
>
> Dim arrDPID
> arrDPID = Array()
> For i = 52 to 66
>   ReDim Preserve arrDPID( UBound(arrDPID) + 1 )
>   arrDPID( UBound(arrDPID) ) = iValues(i)
> Next
> ' <--- Create an array to hold the valid characters for a microsoft Product Key --->
> Dim arrChars
> arrChars = Array("B","C","D","F","G","H","J","K","M","P","Q","R","T","V","W","X","Y","2","3","4","6","7","8","9")
>
> ' <--- The clever bit !!! (Decrypt the base24 encoded binary data) --->
> For i = 24 To 0 Step -1
>   k = 0
>   For j = 14 To 0 Step -1
>     k = k * 256 Xor arrDPID(j)
>     arrDPID(j) = Int(k / 24)
>     k = k Mod 24
>   Next
>   strProductKey = arrChars(k) & strProductKey
>   ' <--- add the "-" between the groups of 5 Char --->
>   If i Mod 5 = 0 And i <> 0 Then strProductKey = "-" & strProductKey
> Next
> strFinalKey = strProductKey
>
>
> ' <--- This part of the script displays operating system Information and the license Key --->
> strComputer = "."
> Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
>   & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
> Set colOperatingSystems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
>   ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")
> For Each objOperatingSystem in colOperatingSystems
>   strOS   = objOperatingSystem.Caption
>   strBuild   = objOperatingSystem.BuildNumber
>   strSerial   = objOperatingSystem.SerialNumber
>   strRegistered  = objOperatingSystem.RegisteredUser
> Next
>
> Set wshShell=CreateObject("wscript.shell")
> strPopupMsg = strOS & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
> strPopupMsg = strPopupMsg & "Build Number:  " & strBuild & vbNewLine
> strPopupMsg = strPopupMsg & "PID:  " & strSerial & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
> strPopupMsg = strPopupMsg & "Registered to:  " & strRegistered & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
> strPopupMsg = strPopupMsg & "Your Windows Product Key is:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & strFinalKey
> strPopupTitle = "Microsoft Windows License Information"
> wshShell.Popup strPopupMsg,,strPopupTitle,vbCancelOnly+vbinformation
> ```
>
> It messages me the OS version, Product ID, Build version and product
>   key.

Comment: Confirmed and working! Nice find! Save this text as .vbs and it will just run.

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing). You must block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help). I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.

Comment: @WasifHasan Clearly this post was not plagiarized as per the original content before David's edit "*Looks like using using batch or powershell is very tough here. I have found a code in VBScript from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30255656/vbscript-to-return-windows-product-key*".... I assume you were suspended for truly plagiarizing another post; otherwise, seems like you were wrongly accused of something. Welcome to the club if that's the case. A mod will likely delete this comment before you get a chance to oppose to a community manager if this is the post you supposedly "plagiarized".